# Вызов функции после изменения CSS-параметров элемента в DOM-дереве "инструментов разработчика" в браузере

Tags: javascript, css, dom

У меня есть функция и я хочу чтоб она срабатывала после того, как будут внесены CSS-изменения какого либо из элементов в DOM-дереве "инструментов разработчика" в браузере.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: записать весь дом в переменную после её загрузки и постоянно делать проверку на сходство с существующим домом. как-то так.

Comment: И советую почитать ещё про `DOM MutationObserver`

Comment: закинул пример по `DOM MutationObserver`

Answer (score 1):

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        console.log('style changed!'); //Здесь логика
    });    
});

var target = document.getElementById("ID ОТСЛЕЖИВАЕМОГО ЭЛЕМЕНТА");
observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] })
```

Answer (score -1):

А это чуточку извращений на JQ. ))) Мож кому понадобится.

```js
$(function() {
  var $domReady = $('html').clone().html()
  setInterval(function() {
    $domReady === $('html').clone().html() ? console.log('DOM not changed') : console.log('Dom is change');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```